# Collapse/Combining multiple adjacent rows conditional on other variables in r

Tags: r, date

```
  day            Timestamp       area    A    B    C
 <date>        <S3: POSIXct>    <chr>  <dbl><dbl><dbl>

2019-08-28  2019-08-28 00:30:00 area1   4   NA  NA
2019-08-28  2019-08-28 00:30:01 area1   NA  NA  1
2019-08-28  2019-08-28 00:30:02 area1   NA  8   NA
2019-08-28  2019-08-28 00:30:03 area2   8   NA  NA
2019-08-28  2019-08-28 00:30:04 area2   NA  NA  1
2019-08-28  2019-08-28 00:30:04 area2   NA  8   NA
2019-08-28  2019-08-28 00:30:06 area3   18  NA  NA
.
.
.
```

I want to combine the rows of the same `day` and `area` , such that it becomes

```
  day            Timestamp     area    A    B    C
 <date>        <S3: POSIXct>   <chr>  <dbl><dbl><dbl>

2019-08-28  2019-08-28 00:30:00 area1   4   8   1


2019-08-28  2019-08-28 00:30:03 area2   8   8   1


2019-08-28  2019-08-28 00:30:06 area3   18  ... ...
.
.
.
```

The issue is with the date. I created `day` from `Timestamp` using `day = as.Date(Timestamp)` but the format of the date data is giving me a bit of the headache. Please kindly advise, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr` one can group by date and area and select the first value which is non.NA:

```
df %>%group_by(day,area)%>%
  summarise_all(~first(na.omit(.)))
```

Comment: Hi Carles, thanks for your answer, I realised that some area may not have  all 3 values for A,B,C. r throws an error `Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys. Keys are shared for 1362 rows: * 3551, 3828 * 4292, 4375 * 11272, 11460, 11463 * 13604, 13649 * 17799, 17993 * 23293, 23433, 23436 * 23338...` Do you think that could be the reason? Thanks again!